# Successfully installed Ubuntu but I never saw Windows outlined by this walkthrough

Tags: system-installation, 12.10

While following this guide [Install Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS](http://web.archive.org/web/20130813224645/http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support), I was never given an option to install over Windows and wipe it out. How do I do that?
I am running a new Dell XPS with Windows 7 Premium.

Comment: Restart the installation again, the step 4 should be there.

Answer (score 0):

In step 4 (Allocate Drive Space step) in the above link you have used ,You where suppossed to select replace windows with ubuntu.

See the image below

[image: Replace and install windows]

Comment: That's the problem.  I never saw any of those windows.  There were very few.  Yet it was installed.

Comment: Whih Ubuntu are you running??